# Insert NULL into DATE field MySQL 5.6

Tags: php, mysql

I seem to be running into an issue inserting NULL into a DATE field in MySQL 5.6. The error is Error Code: 1292. Incorrect date value: '' for column 'StartDate' at row 1.

Here is the table description. The StartDate and EndDate are both DATE type, NULLABLE and default value of NULL.

Active  bit(1)  NO      b'1'
ClientContact   varchar(255)    YES
ClientID    int(11) unsigned    NO  MUL
ClientReferenceNumber   varchar(100)    YES
Description mediumtext  YES
EndDate date    YES
HourlyRate  decimal(6,2)    YES
Hours   int(11) YES
Notes   text    YES
OffShoreAmount  decimal(10,2)   YES
OnShoreAmount   decimal(10,2)   YES
ParentWorkOrderID   int(11) unsigned    YES MUL
ReferenceNumber varchar(100)    YES
StartDate   date    YES
TotalAmount decimal(10,2)   YES
WorkOrderID int(10) unsigned    NO  PRI     auto_increment
WorkOrderTypeID int(10) unsigned    NO  MUL

However the following queries do NOT work.

```
INSERT INTO WorkOrder
    (ParentWorkOrderID, WorkOrderTypeID, ClientID, ReferenceNumber, ClientReferenceNumber,
    Description, StartDate, EndDate, OnShoreAmount, OffShoreAmount, TotalAmount, HourlyRate, 
    Hours, Notes, Active, ClientContact)
VALUES (NULL, 1, 89, 'et-care-001', 'HG453443', '', '', '', 10, 0, 10, NULL, NULL,
        '', 1, 'Jebus');

INSERT INTO WorkOrder
    (ParentWorkOrderID, WorkOrderTypeID, ClientID, ReferenceNumber, ClientReferenceNumber,
    Description, StartDate, EndDate, OnShoreAmount, OffShoreAmount, TotalAmount, HourlyRate, 
    Hours, Notes, Active, ClientContact)
VALUES (NULL, 1, 89, 'et-care-001', 'HG453443', '', '', '', 10, 0, 10, 'NULL', 'NULL',
        '', 1, 'Jebus');
```

I'm positive this was working in MySQL 5.5. What is the proper way to insert null into the field?

Comment: You're not inserting `NULL`, you're inserting an empty string.

Comment: Ahhh you are right, something happened to the PHP code during a merge and the values and columns was in the wrong order

Answer (score 0):

Insert `NULL` and not ''. Also, `'Null'` is not equal to `NULL`

```
INSERT INTO WorkOrder (
    ParentWorkOrderID, 
    WorkOrderTypeID, 
    ClientID, 
    ReferenceNumber, 
    ClientReferenceNumber,   
    Description, 
    StartDate, 
    EndDate, 
    OnShoreAmount, 
    OffShoreAmount, 
    TotalAmount, 
    HourlyRate,  
    Hours, 
    Notes, 
    Active, 
    ClientContact
    ) VALUES (
    NULL, 
    1, 
    89, 
    'et-care-001', 
    'HG453443', 
    '', 
    '',         
    '', 
    10, 
    0, 
    10, 
    NULL, 
    NULL,
    NULL, 
    1, 
    'Jebus');
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to insert null into a field is by using `NULL`.

For example, for a field you may specify values such as `'thisisastring'` and `1`. `NULL` is also valid and only acceptable if the field allows nulls. Note: `''` means an empty string, not null and `'null'` means a string that contains the word null.

For null checking you use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`

Hope that helps.