# How to insert a VARCHAR data in a NULL field

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I have a database in which there are `NOT NULL` and `NULL` fields (the `NULL`s are of the `VARCHAR` type).
 
When I try to enter data in the `NULL` fields via my query, it does not insert them.
The data isn't entered all at the same time:

- with a form I insert the data in the `NOT NULL` fields
- with another form insert the data in the `NULL` fields.

Why doesn't the query for entering data in the `NULL` fields sork?
 
I tried to find an answer to similar questions, but they don't work or are not suitable for my problem:

1. [MySQL Insert Select - NOT NULL fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671853/mysql-insert-select-not-null-fields)
2. [Insert NULL into DATE field MySQL 5.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391566/insert-null-into-date-field-mysql-5-6)

FIRST FORM register.php

```
<?php

   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
  // echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];  // /home1/demonuts/public_html
//including the database connection file
       include_once("config.php");

    $id_akR = $_POST['id_akR'];
    $numero_telefonoR = $_POST['numero_telefonoR'];


     if($id_akR == '' || $numero_telefonoR == '' ){
            echo json_encode(array( "status" => "false","message" => "Parameter missing!") );
     }else{

            $query= "SELECT * FROM RistoratoreAK WHERE id_akR='$id_akR' OR numero_telefonoR ='$numero_telefonoR' ";
            $result= mysqli_query($con, $query);

            $query2 = "SELECT ak_id, numero_telefono FROM AccountKit WHERE ak_id = '$id_akR' OR numero_telefono = '$numero_telefonoR'";
            $result2= mysqli_query($con, $query2);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){  
               echo json_encode(array( "status" => "false","message" => "User already exist in Ristoratore!") );
            }else if(mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
            echo json_encode(array( "status" => "false","message" => "User already exist in Cliente!") );

            }else{ 
             $query = "INSERT INTO RistoratoreAK (id_akR, numero_telefonoR) VALUES ('$id_akR','$numero_telefonoR')";
             if(mysqli_query($con,$query)){

                 $query= "SELECT * FROM RistoratoreAK WHERE numero_telefonoR ='$numero_telefonoR'";
                         $result= mysqli_query($con, $query);
                     $emparray = array();
                         if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){  
                         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                     $emparray[] = $row;
                                   }
                         }
                echo json_encode(array( "status" => "true","message" => "Successfully registered!" , "data" => $emparray) );
             }else{
                 echo json_encode(array( "status" => "false","message" => "Error occured, please try again!") );
            }
        }
                mysqli_close($con);
     }
     } else{
            echo json_encode(array( "status" => "false","message" => "Error occured, please try again!") );
    }

 ?>
```

*SECOND FORM register2.php*

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

include 'config2R.php'; 

 $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);

 $nome = $_POST['nomeR'];
 $cognome = $_POST['cognomeR'];
 $data_nascita = $_POST['data_nascitaR'];
 $sesso = $_POST['sessoR'];
 $nome_ristorante = $_POST['nome_ristoranteR'];


 $CheckSQL = "SELECT nome_ristorante FROM RistoratoreAK WHERE nome_ristorante='$nome_ristorante'";

 $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$CheckSQL));

 if(isset($check)){

 echo 'Ristorante già registrato';

 }
else{ 
$Sql_Query = "INSERT INTO RistoratoreAK (nomeR,cognomeR,data_nascitaR,sessoR,nome_ristorante) values ('$nome','$cognome','$data_nascita','$sesso','$nome_ristorante')";

 if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query))
{
 echo 'Registration Successfully';
}
else
{
 echo 'Something went wrong';
 }
 }
}
 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

My DB contains a table called "RistoratoreAK", the fields are :

```
 id                   INT PrimaryKey
 id_ak                VARCHAR NOT NULL
 number               VARCHAR NOT NULL
 nomeR                VARCHAR NULL
 cognomeR             VARCHAR NULL
 sessoR               VARCHAR NULL
 data_nascitaR        VARCHAR NULL
 nome_ristorante      VARCHAR NULL
```

*note: Excuse me if the code isn't secure (I didn't use PDO), this code is just a test to learn how to upload data to the database.*

Comment: They told me that to prevent attacks from SQL Injection PDO is better than mysqli

Comment: with that insert query you are trying to create an entry that has no values for all the NOT NULL fields. Which obviously doesn't work. When inserting data, you *must*  fill all NOT NULL columns.

Comment: @Cashbee I have two forms, in the first Form I insert the NOT NULL fields, then with the second form I go to insert the NULL fields filling the table.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: @IncredibleHat How can I do? id_ak and number are saved first with the first form.
I can not insert them again.
Can it work if I put all NULL fields?

Comment: @IncredibleHat   Thank you for the help but I can not understand well, could you show me a quick example? I would be grateful to you, it's not easy to find people available like you who are helping me.

Comment: @S.Bruziches in this case, your mistake is that you use `INSERT` instead of `UPDATE`. (only replacing insert with update in your query is not enough, update has other syntax)

Comment: I have modify the question, i have insert a php code to First Form, which I use to insert first id_ak and number.

Comment: @Cashbee i use :   $Sql_Query = "UPDATE RistoratoreAK SET nomeR='$nome', cognomeR='$cognome', data_nascitaR='$data_nascita', sessoR='$sesso', nome_ristorante='$nome_ristorante'";       but does not work

Comment: who voted my question negatively and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first form, you INSERT a new entry into your table with the id and id_ak. This is fine, and it works.

But after the second form, you should not INSERT another entry, but UPDATE an existing one instead (the one that you created before).
To update it, you need to know the id of the existing entry.

Having that, you can make an UPDATE query like this:

```
UPDATE 
    RistoratoreAK
SET
    nomeR = '$nome',
    cognomeR = '$cognome',
    data_nascitaR = '$data_nascita',
    sessoR = '$sesso',
    nome_ristorante = '$nome_ristorante'
WHERE 
    id = $existing_id
```

Comment: the id is called "ID", but it is auto incremented.
In the $ existing_id variable, what do I use?
Should I just state it, or should I use it in the SELECT?

Comment: you could use `mysqli_insert_id($con)` after inserting it to find out its autogenerated ID. Then write it into the second form in a hidden element, so you can read/use it after the second form was submitted.

Comment: Now I try, then I'll let you know how it went.
For now, thank you, you have been a great help to CascBee

Comment: Oh and just a tip: instead of echoing "Something went wrong" when the query didnt work, try echoing useful information about the error. `mysqli_error($con);` is so much more helpful than "something went wrong". You would have found your error so much faster ;)